# Classification of scanned documents in pdf files using deep learning or NLP

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, image-classification, similar-documents

I know classifying images using cnn but I have a problem where I have multiple types of scanned documents in a pdf file on different pages. Some types of scanned documents present in multiple pages inside the pdf.

Now I have to classify and return which documents are present and the page numbers in which they present in the pdf document. If scanned document is in multiple pages I should return the range of page numbers like "1 - 10".

**Input** will be pdf files containing scanned target documents

**Output** should be classified "Document Name" and Its "page numbers"

Can any one guide me on how can I a build a model that can address this problem.

Thankyou

Comment: Do you have training data with known targets (type of doc) or is this a unsupervized problem?

Comment: This is an unsupervised problem, I only had pdf files with images in them

Comment: Did you check pagewise topic modeling?

Comment: No I am new to this topic

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a unsupervized problem, you need to try to extract "topics" using topic modeling. There are a number of tools available in Python, e.g. from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-topics-extraction-with-nmf-lda-py) or [spacy](https://spacy.io/).

Basic workflow:

- Extract [text from PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837707/how-to-extract-text-from-a-pdf-file)
- Text preprocessing (lowercase, [stemming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647400/what-is-the-best-stemming-method-in-python) etc)
- Topic modeling
- Return "topic" per page

Comment: so classification should be on topic text...but we have some features like logos and company names, tables in the pdf pages...which might help in classification

Comment: I don’t think that you can do both text and image classification in one model (i.e. in an unsupervized setting). However, you could see if you can train a second model on images/logos and combine the output of the two models.